# how to Pass the value of listbox from jsp to servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

my javascript  is

```
function takeListBoxValue()
    {
        document.frmPartnerList.submit();
        var selectArray = new Array();   
        for (i = 0; i < partnerList.length; i++)
                {
                    selectArray[i] = new Array();  
                    selectArray[i][0] = partnerList.options[i].text; 
                    selectArray[i][1] = partnerList.options[i].value; 
                }
                document.frmPartnerList.<%=RateCardConstant.ACTION_MODE_PARAMETER%>.value='<%=(new Long(RateCardActionConstant.PARTNER_DOMAIN_LIST_ACTION).toString())%>&dataValue='+selectArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS for this. Just HTML is enough.

```
<form action="servleturl" method="post">
    <select name="listbox" multiple="true">
        <option value="value1">label1</option>
        <option value="value2">label2</option>
        <option value="value3">label3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And then in the servlet use [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) to obtain the selected values:

```
String[] listbox = request.getParameterValues("listbox");
```